Flip round axis on time series data not formatted per time in Google Sheets
I have the attached Google Sheet. I can generate the chart on the right fine - which shows floors on the x-axis and time on the y-axis. However, i'm really struggling to swap this around - so that time is on the x-axis and floors on the y-axis. I think the main reason for this is that the hours data is the one changing, not the floors data. How would I go about sorting this?



Floor
Completed
Hours
Predicted
Taken
Completed
Hours (Floor 8)
Predicted (Floor 8)
Taken
Floor




0
615
0
0.5

615
0
1.9

0


1
2K
1
1.1
0.6
2K
1
0.7
-1.2
1


2
19K
5
3.6
2.5
19K
5
2.3
1.6
2


3
27K
8
8.1
4.4
27K
8
6.8
4.5
3


4
59K
16
14.4
6.3
59K
16
14.0
7.3
4


5
66K
18
22.7
8.3
66K
18
24.1
10.1
5



I tried to create the chart on the right flipped, but it just provides hours vs hours, or one set of hours vs floors, but then when adding another column it fails.
example chart / sheet currently
